# HttpClient returning error 404 on ASP.NET Core on IIS but works on IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1, iis-10

Here is the code

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{       
    // This url is just for testing and the file really exist 
    byte[] data = client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://pngimg.com/uploads/simpsons/simpsons_PNG96.png").Result; // Returning error 404 here only on IIS

    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var myImg = Image.FromStream(mem))
        {
            // If you want it as Png
            myImg .Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

This works in IIS Express but return an error 404 on IIS server; I was trying to debug from VS but with IIS (Windows 10Pro), it does not works, it is also not working when deployed on IIS (Windows server 2016).

The application is a web service built on top of .NET Core 2.1.

Am I missing something in IIS or in the app setting to make it work?

i also try this code:

```
               using (WebClient client1 = new WebClient())
            {
               var a =  client1.DownloadData(new Uri("http://pngimg.com/uploads/simpsons/simpsons_PNG96.png"));
            }
```

but i'm getting the same result.

In both code i'm getting 200 OK with IIS Express and VS, and with IIS in Visual studio debug, i'm getting the following result:

```
 ((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).CharacterSet   "iso-8859-1"    string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).ContentEncoding null    string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).ContentLength   309 long
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).ContentType "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).Cookies {System.Net.CookieCollection}   System.Net.CookieCollection
((System.Net.WebException)e).Response   {System.Net.HttpWebResponse}    System.Net.WebResponse {System.Net.HttpWebResponse}
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).Headers {Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 17:46:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15, (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Length: 309
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
}   System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
((System.Net.WebException)e).Response.IsFromCache   false   bool
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).IsMutuallyAuthenticated false   bool
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).LastModified    {2019-11-15 1:09:53 PM} System.DateTime
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).Method  "GET"   string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).ProtocolVersion {1.1}   System.Version
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).ResponseUri {http://pngimg.com/uploads/simpsons/simpsons_PNG96.png} System.Uri
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).Server  "Apache/2.2.15, (CentOS)"   string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).StatusCode  NotFound    System.Net.HttpStatusCode
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).StatusDescription   "Not Found" string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response).SupportsHeaders true    bool
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._characterSet   "iso-8859-1"    string
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._cookies    {System.Net.CookieCollection}   System.Net.CookieCollection
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._httpResponseMessage    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 17:46:35 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.15
  Server: (CentOS)
  Connection: close
  Content-Length: 309
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._isVersionHttp11    true    bool
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._requestUri {http://pngimg.com/uploads/simpsons/simpsons_PNG96.png} System.Uri
((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)e).Response)._webHeaderCollection    {Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 17:46:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15, (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Length: 309
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
}   System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
```

Edit: add picture exception
[image]

The error form http request:

> ((System.AggregateException)e).Message    "One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)"   string

Comment: can you post picture of your local iis?  is the application actually setup as an application (right click and choose convert to application) what do you get when you navigate to the url in a browser? and is it actually on port 80(http)?

Comment: If you intend to save the image locally, there's no reason to use `Image` or `MemoryStream`. Just save the byte array to the path you want with `File.WriteAllBytes(path,data)`

Comment: IIS *doesn't* affect how HttpClient works. If you get a 404 it means that either the URL isn't correct or a firewall rule on the server blocks access to that domain. BTW `HttpClient` should be reused, not disposed. You shouldn't use `.Result` to block, you should make your own methods asynchronous and use `await client.GetByteArrayAsync(...)`. Debugging in IIS works too (I use it all the time). Did you get an error?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The code is working well in Debug, but i can Get request return a 200 Ok if debug with IIS Express. The web application is also working well when debugging with IIS , The IIS debug is configured and is working well. The only thing that is not working is that Http Get Request. the link is working, you can open that link in the browser and the image will show itself. About the `.Result` i'm aware about it but that may not the problem because the same code works with IIS Express.

Comment: how about adding logs so you get the exception message or inner exception ? this problem probably doesn't have anything to do with IIS.

Comment: @grabhints In Visual studio, i['m able to debug with IIS directly so i'm able to see the error returned from the Http Request, my problem is that i'm not able to understand why the 404 error is happening while the target file really exist, and why the same Http Request (same code) is returning 200Ok on IISExpress.

Comment: When you run on IIS Express and IIS, the contexts differ significantly, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Very likely that IIS Express picks up your user credentials and sends to the site, so 404 is not returned in that case. Use a tool like Wireshark to capture your HTTP requests in both cases and compare them.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you, i will check try the tools to compare both request.